# How to assign a static IP to a pod using Kubernetes on deployment

Tags: containers, kubernetes

I am trying to assign a static IP address to a pod on deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aws-test-mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aws-test-mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aws-test-mysql
        image: 461677341235123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws-test-mysql
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          hostIP: 172.20.32.50
          hostPort: 3306
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ecrkey
```

As you can see when I described my pod it is created with another IP.

```
test-mbp1:aws test$ kubectl describe pods | grep IP
IP:     100.96.1.3
```

I'm trying to deploy a pod with a static IP on "kind: Deployment" and not as a service.

Is this posible ?

Comment: we can't assign static IP address to POD. we need to create the service and add selecter as POD label. then use service  IP/dns name to access your pod.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip

Answer (score 7):

A static IP cannot be assigned to a Pod because of the dynamic nature of kubernetes' IP layer.

Since you don't want to attach a Service (which is the best way imho), a close alternative is to convert the Deployment to a StatefulSet. This will give the Pod a static hostname which more-or-less fulfils your requirement.

The first replica of the StatefulSet will be called `aws-test-mysql-0.<kubernetes.cluster.tld>`.

Comment: Thanks!, I actually went with the service route since a static IP cannot be assigned to a Pod. However, I will look into statefullset as well. thanks for the info.

Comment: Any chance you know this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848298/automatic-spot-pricing-for-kops-deployment