# automatic spot pricing for kops deployment

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kops

I can already do spot deployments with kops but it requires manually editing a the instance groups (nodes)

```
$ kops edit ig --name=test.dev.test.com nodes
  machineType: t2.medium
  maxSize: 2
  minSize: 2
=>
  machineType: t1.nano
  maxSize: 1
  minSize: 1
```

Need to look into a way of doing this automatically with the average spot price + 10%

I would also like to have at least 1 master and 1 node that are running on normal instances to survive a complete spot-overbid shutdown and the rest to spot price.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Argo minion-manager. This is part of open-source workflow engine for Kubernetes [Argo](http://argoproj.io) , but can be run on any kubernetes cluster. Minion-manager runs as deployment and periodically updates spot instance prices using the AWS pricing API.

More information about minion-manager is available here: https://blog.argoproj.io/use-spot-instances-with-your-kubernetes-clusters-on-aws-2a27f1887bb0

Comment: using [kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam) and Argo's Minion-Manager with Kops, and despite an issue with kubelet not able to start ([workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/3605#issuecomment-351674234)) it seems to work alright

Comment: Minion-Manager's source code is now availabe here: https://github.com/argoproj/k8s-minion-manager/