# how to configure an internal static ip for pod inside of minikube

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, kubernetes, minikube

I want to deploy a nginx-server-pod that mounts a directory to serve the files of that directory to my consumer-pod, that also lives on minikube.

In order to start consumer-pod I need to pass the ip of this nginx-server-pod to the configuration files of my-pod **before** it is scheduled or deployed. I do not want to expose nginx-server-pod outside minikube, so I don't want a services that create an external port mapping of type minikube-ip:external-port . I know that internal Cluser-IPs change and cannot be discovered until after the pod is deployed.

Any ideas on how to set an unchanging internal ip for my nginx-server-pod before deployment so I can configure consumer-pod and they can be deployed together?

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465228/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-to-a-pod-using-kubernetes-on-deployment

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for your nginx container.  It can be a ClusterIP service if it doesn't need to be accessible outside the cluster (or minikube VM).  Once the service exists, it will have a [DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) of something like `nginx.default.svc.cluster.local`.  You can put *that* in your config file and it will be consistent regardless of what IP address(es) the nginx pod(s) (if any) has.